# Overriding attributes in embedded doctrine entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am using symfony Symfony 5.2. I have an Embeddable entity called Address, that contains fields like street, house and so on.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Embeddable()
 */
class Address {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true, name="street", length=Constants::MAX_STREET_NAME_LENGTH)
     */
    private string $street;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true, name="house")
     */
    private int $house;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true, name="flat")
     */
    private int $flat;
    //More fields
```

There are two more entities that use this embeddable, User and Order.
User:

```
class User implements UserInterface {
    //Some code here
    /**
     * @Assert\Valid
     * @ORM\Embedded (class="\App\Entity\Embeddable\Address", columnPrefix="user_")
     */
    private Address $address;
```

Order:

```
class Order {
    //Some more fields
    /**
     * @Assert\Valid
     * @ORM\Embedded (class="\App\Entity\Embeddable\Address", columnPrefix="order_")
     */
    private Address $address;
}
```

Here is the main problem. I want to override the column annotations for user to allow null values in address fields, such as street, and for order to not allow it. I know there is an annotation called `@AttributeOverride` but for some reason it is not working, I can't generate the migration or validate the database schema. The error I get is:

```
Invalid field override named 'address.street' for class 'App\Entity\Order'
```

Annotation I use for Order:

```
@AttributeOverrides({
   @AttributeOverride(name="address.street", column=@ORM\Column (type="string", 
   length=Constants::MAX_STREET_NAME_LENGTH, nullable=false))
 })
```

So the question is: is there a way to use annotations attribute overriding for embedded entities?

Comment: I've tried many things and it doesn't seem to be working. It seems to work with extended superclasses and traits, but not with embedded classes.

Comment: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/association-mapping.html. I think you should try @ORM\ManyToOne.